# How to use Tri-Secret Key in Snowflake after Snowflake support enabled it for your account

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, encryption-symmetric

I contacted snowflake support and send them my KMS AWS ARN and they enabled Tri Secret Secure feature for my account. But now how can I use it after they enable it for my account. They didn't give me any key or anything. How will I get my Tri Secret Key? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Use this [article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-test-Tri-Secret-Secure-is-enabled) to test Tri-Secret after it was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

By default, All data stored in Snowflake is transparently encrypted using a key hierarchy (with cloud HSM backed root of trust), which provides enhanced security by encrypting individual pieces of data using a different key.

With Tri-Secret Secure enabled for your account, Snowflake combines your key with a Snowflake-maintained key to create a composite master key. This composite master key is then used to encrypt all data in your account. If either key in the composite master key is revoked, your data cannot be decrypted, providing a level of security and control above Snowflake’s standard encryption. This dual-key encryption model, together with Snowflake’s built-in user authentication, enables the three levels of data protection offered by Tri-Secret Secure.

For more details about the implementation of customer-managed keys, see this [blog post](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/customer-managed-keys/) (which references AWS, although the general principles apply regardless of cloud service).

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/customer-managed-keys/